# Matplotlib annotate doesn't work on log scale?

Tags: matplotlib, annotate

I am making log-log plots for different data sets and need to include the best fit line equation. I know where in the plot I should place the equation, but since the data sets have very different values, I'd like to use relative coordinates in the annotation. (Otherwise, the annotation would move for every data set.)

I am aware of the annotate() function of matplotlib, and I know that I can use textcoords='axes fraction' to enable relative coordinates. When I plot my data on the regular scale, it works. But then I change at least one of the scales to log and the annotation disappears. I get no error message.

Here's my code:

```
plt.clf()
samplevalues = [100,1000,5000,10^4]
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(samplevalues,samplevalues,'o',color='black')
ax.annotate('hi',(0.5,0.5), textcoords='axes fraction')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

If I comment out `ax.set_xcale('log')` and `ax.set_ycale('log')`, the annotation appears right in the middle of the plot (where it should be). Otherwise, it doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I suspect this is related to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1311 which I reported a while ago, but I don't think anyone has track it down yet.  Odds are this is some strange floating point issue.

Comment: @tcaswell would you know how I can report this to the matplotlib developers? Thanks!

Comment: I am one of them so your part of the way there ;)  Can you leave a comment on that issue?  In addition to the code can you also include what version of mpl (`matplotlib.__version__`) your are using?

Comment: @tcaswell I'm using matplotlib 0.99.3. Thanks!

Comment: yikes, that is very old (1.4 will be released 'soon')

Comment: Oh, I'm using the Enthought Python distribution. They tend to have the old versions in the bundle...

Comment: You should update if you can.  I am pretty sure the most recent one include 1.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may really be a bug as pointed out by @tcaswell in the comment but a workaround is to use text() in axis coords:

```
plt.clf()
samplevalues = [100,1000,5000,10^4]
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.loglog(samplevalues,samplevalues,'o',color='black')
ax.text(0.5, 0.5,'hi',transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

Another approach is to use figtext() but that is more cumbersome to use if there are already several plots (panels).

By the way, in the code above, I plotted the data using log-log scale directly. That is, instead of:

```
ax.plot(samplevalues,samplevalues,'o',color='black')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

I did:

```
ax.loglog(samplevalues,samplevalues,'o',color='black')
```